# Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, import, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy my firebase function to cloud but getting an error:

> Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'EmailData'

1.I  compile my ts file to js.

2.the build of ts ok...
my code looks like:

the ts that importing the file...

```
var EmailDataClass = require("EmailData");
```

and the file it self:

```
class EmailData {....
}export = EmailData;
```

> ```
> ✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
> i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
>
> Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'EmailData'
> ```

Comment: So you have a file called EmailData.js in the same directory as your index.js?

Comment: ../functions/lib/index.js  and functions/lib/sendind.q.by.email/emailDataClass.js

Comment: It sounds like you should read up on how `require` works with node.  https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's  not recommended to use mix of Typescript & ES6 export and import methods

it's better to use type script import

```
import { EmailDataClass } from "./EmailData";
```

And to Export use

```
export class EmailData {....
}
```

Comment: is there any way to keep using the declared path (as in this question `EmailData`) rather than `./EmailData` I have other code for front end which are the same so i dont wanna keep changing every time i update either the frontend or the backend.